# Can´t retrieve entity with negative double in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am loading a list of entities of `Amounts.class` and the list contains all the entries of my table except those with a negative value;

```
@Table(name = "amounts")
public class Amounts implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "payment_id")
   private long payment_id;


   @Column(name = "amount",length = 10,precision = 2)
   private Double amount;

   //getters and setters
}
```

I defined the length and precission to fit it exactly as my table
but no entry with a negative value in the amount field (-1400.00, -10.50 and so on) is loaded.

How can I solve this?
I have tried the primitive double and Double, with and without precission.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first verify that your table schema is actually using a column that allows for negative values (FLOAT, DOUBLE)

Also, the `length` element of the Column annotation applies *only if a string-valued column is used*. You should use the following instead:

```
@Column(precision=10, scale=2)
```

Comment: My table is storing the negative values with no errors, when i use plain JDBC to get the entries it retrieve all entries correctly, but with persistance (hibernate and javax persistance) it does not return entries with negative numeric values. In my database the values are stored in decimal(10,2) signed

Comment: Already tried java BigDecimal in the mapping model but the result is the same